# How do I for...in loop though this JSON array of multiple cookies to get the key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, cookies

I may be going about this all wrong, so I value any input and suggestions...
I am trying to save panel states in a custom UI by setting cookies during the click function using the [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) (formerly jquery-cookie) plugin.

Here is the action that I use to open/close panels, which I have added an if/else statement to set or remove the cookies.

```
$(".panel-collapse").on("click",function(){
    panel_collapse($(this).parents(".panel"));
    $(this).parents(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
    var panelid = $(this).closest('.panel').attr('id');
    var cookieChk = Cookies.get(panelid);
    if (cookieChk == null) {
        Cookies.set(panelid, 'closed');
    } else {
        Cookies.remove(panelid, 'closed');
    }

    return false;
});
```

This works all fine and dandy to create the cookies I need for my panels with the key being the panel's ID and the value being "closed".

I was then trying to use those cookies to save the panels' closed states.

With js-cookie I can then use

```
Cookies.getJSON();
```

And if I log to console it will return all of my cookies like so:

```
Object {pnl1: "closed", pnl2: "closed"} and so forth...
```

So it seems to be returning what I need. What I'd like to do is run a loop through this to set the panels with cookies to be closed. How would I go about doing this? Or is this totally the wrong way to go about accomplishing my goal?

Javascript is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, a simple for..in would do the trick:

```
var cookies = Cookies.getJSON();
for(var id in cookies) {
    $('#'+id).hide(); // hiding the closed panel, for example
}
```

Inside the loop, `id` is the key, and the value is `cookie[id]`.

---

Here's a simple demo:

```js
var cookies = {pnl1: "closed", pnl2: "closed", pnl4: "blue"};

for (var id in cookies) {
  $('#' + id).addClass(cookies[id]); // give it a class of the cookie value
}
```

```css
div {color: green}
.closed {color: red}
.blue {color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pnl1">Panel 1</div>
<div id="pnl2">Panel 2</div>
<div id="pnl3">Panel 3</div>
<div id="pnl4">Panel 4</div>
```